# Create a new animation from TListViewItem PlaceOffset not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, layout-animation

I have a problem to animate an item in a `TListView` in the `PlaceOffset`. How can I do it?

I want to change the `X` and `Y` position of an item in a `TListView` from

`position.X = -56` to `position.X = 144`

and

`position.Y = 16` to `position.Y = 96`

[image]

I can do it without animation like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item : TListViewItem;
begin
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Data['Text1'] := 'Animate Me in postion  x =136 y =256 ';
  //  PlaceOffset.X := 8;
  //  PlaceOffset.Y := 8;
  item.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text1').PlaceOffset.X := 136;
  item.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text1').PlaceOffset.Y := 256;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item : TListViewItem;
begin
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Data['Text1'] := 'Animate Me in postion  x =8 y =8';
  item.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text1').PlaceOffset.X := 8;
  item.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text1').PlaceOffset.Y := 8;
end;
```

But how can I do it with `TFloatAnimation`?

[image]